# Calculating amount of information gained by getting partial data

Tags: information-theory

**Set up:** Let's say I have a bag with 12 notes containing strings of text made up of the letters A-L.

**Action:** Someone pulls one note out from that hat, then at random they choose 2 letters written on their note, and tell those letters to me.

**Goal:** I'm trying to calculate the average amount of information I get by knowing any 2 letters off their note.

Case study:

To make it super flushed out, let's assume these are the notes in the hat:

1. ACEFHJL
2. ABDFGIK
3. BCEGHJL
4. ACDFHIK
5. BDEGIJL
6. ACEFHJK
7. BDFGIKL
8. ACEGHJL
9. ABDFHIK
10. BCEGIJL
11. ACDFHJK
12. BDEGIKL

**Example 1:**

If for instance, this person tells me their note contains the letters A and B, I know they are either holding note number 2, or note number 9, since those are the two notes containing both A and B. This therefore, cuts the space of possibilities from 12 down to 2, equivalent to about 2.58 bits of information.

**Example 2:**

If on the other hand, they tell me their note contains the letters A and F, it would mean that the note they are holding is number 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, or 11, since they all contain both A and F. This in turn only cuts the space in possibilities in half, thus providing only 1 bit of information.

**Recap:**

So, we see that knowing some 2-letter combinations (like AB) provide more information than others (like AF). I would like calculate the average amount of information I get by knowing any 2 letters? That is to say, if we repeated this exercise a million times, each time, this person would shuffle the notes in the hat and pull out one. Then at random tell me 2 letters off of that note. How much information will I gain on average?

**Flushing it all out:**

Here's another example. Let's say this time I have a bag with the following notes in it:

1. ACEG
2. ABDF
3. BCEG
4. ACDF
5. BDEG
6. ACEF
7. BDFG

Below is a table with the information gained by knowing the selected note contains any 2 letters

| Letter combo | p(E) | I(E) | Appears in: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 2 |
| AC | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 1, 4, 6 |
| AD | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 2, 4 |
| AE | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 1, 6 |
| AF | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 2, 4, 6 |
| AG | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 1 |
| BC | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 3 |
| BD | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 2, 5, 7 |
| BE | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 3, 5 |
| BF | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 2, 7 |
| BG | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 3, 5, 7 |
| CD | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 4, |
| CE | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 1, 3, 6 |
| CF | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 4, 6 |
| CG | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 1, 3 |
| DE | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 5 |
| DF | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 2, 4, 7 |
| DG | 0.29 (2/7) | 1.79 | 5, 7 |
| EF | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 6 |
| EG | 0.43 (3/7) | 1.22 | 1, 3, 5 |
| FG | 0.14 (1/7) | 2.84 | 7 |

How do I compute the average information gained by selecting a random row from this table?

Comment: You did assume a uniform PMF over the set of twelve notes.  Have you tried assuming a uniform PMF over the set of 2-letters?

Comment: You can't assume anything about the distribution of letters. But you have the full list of notes along with their contents. So you can iteratively compute the information gained from every pair of letters. Question is, once I have a list of the amount of information I gain from every pair of letters, how do I them combine those into an one value expressing the average amount of information gain for ANY 2 letters?

Comment: How so?  To measure the information gain, one must compute the Shannon entropies before and after the information is gained, right?  Since you are relying on the support only, it is safe to assume that you are implicitly assuming the use of the uniform PMF (which maximizes the Shannon entropy).

Comment: Ok, let's say we assume the uniform PMF, how would you then compute the average information? I must admit I'm very much out of my depth. This is not my usual discipline.

Comment: I added a little follow up to my question that may or may not be useful. I hope it is though.

Comment: Just take the appropriate weighted average of the information gained, over the possible letter pairs. The weight for a pair should be the probability that the person tells you the pair (not the probability that the selected note contains the pair) so that the weights sum to 1.

Comment: Your table does not contain the "combo" KL, does it?

Comment: @Karl, that was what I was missing. Thank you! You completely solved my problem!